# SQL and VB.NET 2008 Query

Tags: sql, vb.net

Here is what I have:.

```
Con.close()
Con.open()

Query ="Update Products Set QOH = QOH - '" & txtQoH.text & "' Where Prod_ID ='"& textbox1.text & "'"
Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Con.Close().
```

Okay There, I'm trying to update a product quantity on hand once certain number of product is being purchased. So I've tried that and its not working, can somebody help me?

Comment: "It's not working"- what specifically is the problem? One issue is that you shouldn't surround parameters with `''` if they're integers.

Comment: Your query is wide open to a [Sql Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)... you should parameterize your query in order to protect against this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many problems in your code. Let me start to list them.

- First The field `QOH` is numeric right? So don't try to subtract a
  string from a number (The quotes around the textbox)
- Second, you write a query but there is no code that show how do you
  set this text in your command
- Third, a connection should be opened when needed and closed/disposed immediately
  afterwards (The [Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) is fundamental for this)
- Fourth, how do you check if your user inputs numeric values instead
  of bogus strings? A [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) will help here to avoid executing a
  failed query
- Fifth, and this is the most important. DO NOT CONCATENATE strings to
  build sql commands. [Use always a parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

  ```
  Dim qty
  If Int32.TryParse(txtQoH.text, qty) Then
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid numeric quantity")
      Return
  End if
  Dim prodID
  If Int32.TryParse(textBox.text, prodID) Then
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid product ID")
      Return
  End if

  Query ="Update Products Set QOH = QOH - @qty Where Prod_ID = @prodID"
  Using con = new SqlConnection(.....constring here ....)
  Using cmd = new SqlCommand(con, Query)
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", qty)
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodID", prodID)
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
  End Using
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've left out some code, I don't see where you're actually setting the [`CommandText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext.aspx) of the `Command` object:

```
Query ="Update Products Set QOH = QOH - '" & txtQoH.text & "' Where Prod_ID ='"& textbox1.text & "'"

Command.CommandText = Query

Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

You should also use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) instead of string concatenation, but that's another issue...

Answer (score 0):

As first U try to substract one text item (your txtQoH.text) from one integer column. (As I think)

As second, you Prod_ID is one integer colomn too.

Try your query without '

smth. like this:

UPDATE PRODUCTS SET QOH=QOH - 2 WHERE PROD_ID=12312312

or in you code:
Query ="Update Products Set QOH = QOH - " & txtQoH.text & " Where Prod_ID ="& textbox1.text & ""

as I can see..